# Windows Batch File Dateformat without zero

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like my date format not to be displayed as such if the month and day is below a two-digit value:

> 1.18.04.09

But as such:

> 1.18.4.9

My Date variable:

`@set version2= %11.%DATE:~8,2%.%DATE:~3,2%.%DATE:~0,2%%`

How should the command be changed? The zeros before day and month should not be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I offer a solution that doesn't depend on locale date format?

```
FOR /F %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year /value ^|find "="') do set "_%%A"
set version2=%11.%_Year:~2,2%.%_Month%.%_Day%
echo %version2%
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use arithmetic `/A` to make `SET` command return numbers without zeros:

```
@set version2= %11
@set /a v=1%DATE:~8,2%-100
@set version2=%version2%.%v%
@set /a v=1%DATE:~3,2%-100
@set version2=%version2%.%v%
@set /a v=1%DATE:~0,2%-100
@set version2=%version2%.%v%
```

Using 1xx-100 is to avoid octal numbers errors, like 08 and 09.

Answer (score 0):

This also does not depend on regional date format settings.

```
FOR /F %a IN ('powershell -NoProfile -Command "'{0:M-d-yyyy}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(1)"') DO SET "version2=%a"
```

Remember to double the percent characters if used in a .bat file script.